How to organize a project on ASP.NET Core to minimize code duplication?
I started to study ASP.NET Core and how projects are organized on it and a question appeared
For example, I have User, Book and Order entities and I write repositories, services and UseCases for them.
And if I take the same repositories, then for each repository will be the same CRUD operations, get all users/books/orders, get by id users/books/orders, add users/books/orders, delete users/books/orders.
Further in the services is about the same and similar logic and the same in UseCases, what to do, how to remove code doubling, how to organize a large project on ASP.NET Core in general correctly?

I would suggest using repository pattern for generic repository.
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync();
    Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id);
    Task AddAsync(T entity);
    Task UpdateAsync(T entity);
    Task DeleteAsync(int id);
}

and use it like this
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _dbSet.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _dbSet.FindAsync(id);
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(T entity)
    {
        await _dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Update(entity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task DeleteAsync(int id)
    {
        var entity = await GetByIdAsync(id);
        if (entity != null)
        {
            _dbSet.Remove(entity);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}

Also may I suggest to explore about dependency injection

How can di help in my case?

You should use generic repositories and services instead of duplicating code.
For example:
public class Repository<T> 
{
   public T[] Get();
   public T Find();
   public T Create();
   public bool Delete();
}

Then instantiate them with the required types (Book, Order, etc.)
var bookRepository = new Repository<Book>();
var orderRepository = new Repository<Order>();

